# TFS 2013 Reconcile workspace popup not showing

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

We have a gated checkin. When we checkin some files the changes are left in your workspace so you can continue your work. Normally when the build is finished you get a popup to reconcile your workspace. You can reconcile by right clicking the build but I want the popup so you don't forget it.

My colleagues are getting the popup but I don't. I can't find an option to show the popup again. Does somebody have an idea?

We have TFS2013 Update 2 en Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 installed.

Comment: do you have the build notification tray running? seems to work more consistently if it is running

Comment: Yes I have the 2013 version running and the gated checkin build is showing in the list. I also checked the icon/notifications settings of Windows 7 and it is set as "Show icon and notifications".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Just TFS` correctly hinted, the pop-up with "reconcile workspace" is part of [Build Notification application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181725.aspx#App). Visual Studio makes it run automatically at logon - but if you closed it, it won't run unless you re-run it.

Comment: But I haven't closed it. I will try to close it tomorrow, do a restart and open it again. Hopefully than the popups are back...

Comment: I had the build notification already running. Strange that popups (and later not the notification anymore) where showing up. What I did to fix. Removed the builds from the notification, closed all vs instances, cleared the TFS cache in my windows profile, rebooted, and then set everything up again. After that, the notifications are back and the popup is back! Strange... I think something is gone wrong by installing Update 3 for VS2013? I can't think about something else...

Comment: Also, make sure you are running the proper version. My Build Notification app was running the 2013 version, while I was running VS2015

Comment: This was the tip I needed to figure out how to do this manually (right click on the build and select from the context menu).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to wait a couple of minutes after the build was successfully committed